# verbs for when a country ends tariffs

Tags: verbs, government

What verb could be used to describe when country A, which has implemented tariffs on country B, ends/removes/discontinues these tariffs?

e.g. *After the incident, America [X]ed the tariffs.*

Comment: What is wrong with *ended*?

Comment: Some good suggestions below, but I'd also add _removed_.

Answer (score 5):

> After the incident, America **lifted** the tariffs.

> **[lift](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lift)**
>
> > 4 (with object) Formally remove or end (a legal restriction, decision, or ban)
> >     *‘the European Community lifted its oil embargo against South Africa’*

Some headlines:

> U.S. 'might' lift tariffs once new trade deal is signed
>   https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/freeland-carr-meet-with-future-mexican-cabinet-ministers-in-ottawa-1.1156131
>
> Trump faces mounting pressure to lift tariffs on Canada, Mexico
>   https://edition.cnn.com/2018/11/20/politics/steel-aluminum-tariffs-usmca/index.html
>
> Vice President Pence: US Won’t Lift Tariffs Until ‘China Changes Its Ways’
>   https://sputniknews.com/us/201811171069888189-pence-usa-wont-stop-tariffs-china-change/

Answer (score 0):

[Abolish:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abolish) is commonly  used when you refer  to removing taxes, tariffs, regulations etc.

​

> (LAW, GOVERNMENT) to end an activity, custom, etc. completely or by law or official action:
>
> - Educationalists have called on the government to abolish tax on computers.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abolish%20tariffs%2Clift%20tariffs&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabolish%20tariffs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clift%20tariffs%3B%2Cc0): abolish tariffs

Usages:

> Consider a group of countries that ***agree to reduce or abolish tariffs*** on the imports of some commodities from member countries preferentially. From: 
>   [Macroeconomics, Trade, and Social Welfare](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QSapDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA165&dq=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0lqveo5bfAhV_SxUIHWo8A3AQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&f=false)
>
> Prescott Bush (father of future president George Bush), had reservations. Bush later commented: “I never was a free trader. ***I never felt that we could abolish tariffs*** and do away with all protective devices, because we would have been flooded with imports ...
>   From : [Opening America's Market: U.S. Foreign Trade Policy Since 1776](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yxM6hAccvN0C&pg=PT228&dq=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0lqveo5bfAhV_SxUIHWo8A3AQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&f=false)
>
> Implementation of laissez-faire was sometimes thought of as if it were a one- time act: ***after government intervened to abolish tariffs***, usury laws, and other legal restraints on economic ... From: 
>   [The Open Society in Theory and Practice](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JqEyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA331&dq=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvqd_QpJbfAhUHQxUIHQyhDlQ4ChDoAQg0MAM#v=onepage&q=%22abolish%20tariffs%22&f=false)

Comment: Boy, those are a couple a odd drive-bys. Have a +1.

Answer (score -1):

Tariffs established by a legislative body are usually said to be **repealed**. . Nonlegislative tariffs would be **revoked**.  But you don't always want or need to be procedurally accurate, sometimes you want to just emphasize the result. Or you simply may not know the details and don't want to trip over the wrong word.

**Rescind** works well enough for either case.

> 1 : to take away : REMOVE
>   2a : TAKE BACK, CANCEL
>   //refused to rescind the order
>   b : to abrogate (a contract) and restore the parties to the positions they would have occupied had there been no contract
>   3 : to make void by action of the enacting authority or a superior authority : REPEAL
>   //rescind an act

"Rescind." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 10 Dec. 2018.

Some headlines:

> U.S. Chemicals Manufacturers Welcome USMCA Signing, Urge President Trump to Rescind Tariffs on Steel and Aluminum
>   https://www.americanchemistry.com/Media/PressReleasesTranscripts/ACC-news-releases/US-Chemicals-Manufacturers-Welcome-USMCA-Signing.html
>   In Open Letter, Trump Supporting CEO Begs Trump To Rescind Tariffs
>   https://mavenroundtable.io/theintellectualist/news/in-open-letter-trump-supporting-ceo-begs-trump-to-rescind-tariffs-mr8be76zfEeqkZXn_GFaww/
>   US Considering to Rescind Tariffs Based on Talks
>   https://www.redpulse.com/china/20181101/us-considering-to-rescind-tariffs-based-on-talks-3ab1979e85

My sense is that *lift* tends to be used to imply a link between the lifting and the acceptability of trading partners' behavior, whereas *rescind* can be used without implying that the rescission is due to some more favorable regard toward the relationship.